# stuck with object inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance

I'm trying to understand the object inheritance in js by building a base constructor and working through that but its not working for me. I have gone wrong somewhere in my code:

```
function car(make, model, transmission) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.transmission = transmission;
    this.report = function() {
        return ("make " + this.make + "model " + model);
    }

}

function SUV(make, model, transmission, mpg) {
    this.mpg = mpg;
    this.carInfo = car;
    this.carInfo = (make, model, transmission);

}
SUV.prototype = new Car();
SUV.prototype.getMPG = function() {
    return "the suv mpg is" + this.mpg;
}
mySuv = new Suv("nissan", "almera", "manual", 12);
document.writeIn(newSuv + report());
```

Comment: Start by checking your casing.

Comment: You have a couple of case issues `Car`  and `car`.. `SUV` and `Suv`. Also what is `newSuv` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not inherit just by assigning the parent class to an instance method (which you immediately overwrite anyway).

Instead, you must call the parent constructor on `this`:

```
function SUV(...) {
    car.call(this, ...);
    ....
}
```

`call` allows you to specify what `this` will refer to in the parent method. `car.call(this, ...)` is equivalent to:

```
this.car_funk = car
this.car_funk(...);
delete this.car_funk;`
```

Or this:

```
car.bind(this)(...)
```

Comment: ok thanks a million!! good explanation and starting point to get my code right,thanks